# Loading and reading Ruby Marshal dump files in Python

Tags: python, ruby

Simply put, I would like to (if possible) load a Ruby Marshal dump (.dat) file into Python and parse it back into something readable. I've looked into the Pickle, Marshal and RubyMarshal modules but ended up getting errors each time.
The following errors had occured:

Pickle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Saved Games\unmarshal\unmarsh.py", line 2, in <module>
    ma = pickle.load(open('file.dat','rb'))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x04'.
```

Marshal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Saved Games\unmarshal\unmarsh.py", line 2, in <module>
    ma = marshal.load(open('file.dat','rb'))
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

RubyMarshal (using their base example) doesn't error but it doesn't accomplish what I am after, meaning it remains the same.

Any insight on these would be extremely useful.

Comment: You really can't expect `pickle` or `marshal` to read a file that was produced by a different serializer. Your best bet is `RubyMarshal`. What does it do that you don't like, and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Hasn't this question been already asked 1 or 2 times in the last couple of weeks?

Comment: I'm looking to deserialize a file in Python that had been created using Ruby. Also it would be nice to know if that isn't possible.

Comment: The RubyMarshal project says it is at least partially possible, though it can only translate basic datatypes: float, bool, int, str, nil (mapped to None), array (mapped to list) and hash (mapped to dict).

Answer (score 0):

There is library for that: [RubyMarshal](https://github.com/d9pouces/RubyMarshal)

```
from rubymarshal.reader import load
import gzip
with gzip.open('latest_specs.4.8.gz', 'rb') as latest_specs:
    print(load(latest_specs))
```